# Как реализовать переход в папки

Tags: android, файловая-система

Делаю программу, которая получает список данных из Dropbox. Подскажите, как сделать переход в папку, чтобы получать отображение ее содержимого и можно было вернуться назад. В общем как в обычном файловом менеджере.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: эээ... Получить список файлов, отобразить, при нажатии назад отобразить родительскую папку?... Вам что конкретно непонятно-то?

Comment: как именно это реализуется, создается новое активити и в него передаются данные или как?

Comment: Можно и так, можно и на одной активити во фрагментах. Но конкретная реализация будет зависеть от того, в каком виде дропбокс данные отдаёт